# UI component Export data issue : Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, uicomponent

We have created a grid in UI Component. While we have export data from grid we got an error like.

```
{"0":"Notice: Undefined index: attributes in \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php on line 174","1":"#0 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(174): Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined index...', '\/var\/www\/html\/b...', 174, Array)\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/View\/Element\/UiComponentFactory.php(206): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->argumentsResolver(NULL, Array)\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Component\/MassAction\/Filter.php(76): Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponentFactory->create(NULL)\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Model\/Export\/ConvertToCsv.php(60): Magento\\Ui\\Component\\MassAction\\Filter->getComponent()\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-ui\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Export\/GridToCsv.php(72): Magento\\Ui\\Model\\Export\\ConvertToCsv->getCsvFile()\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php(107): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv->execute()\n#6 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/AbstractAction.php(229): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#7 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Backend\\App\\AbstractAction->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#8 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#9 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/module-backend\/App\/Action\/Plugin\/Authentication.php(143): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#10 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Magento\\Backend\\App\\Action\\Plugin\\Authentication->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#11 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#12 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Ui\/Controller\/Adminhtml\/Export\/GridToCsv\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, NULL)\n#13 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php(55): Magento\\Ui\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Export\\GridToCsv\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#14 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#15 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)\n#16 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#17 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)\n#18 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php(135): Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http))\n#19 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch()\n#20 \/var\/www\/html\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/index.php(51): Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http))\n#21 {main}","url":"\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/admin\/mui\/export\/gridToCsv\/key\/478137d7ab452ec87ffbf3c0613afcee2829081df81e1916da6734b91d554bd6\/?","script_name":"\/bannerbuzzmagento2\/index.php"}
```

While I am adding below tag in XML file then its working fine.

```
<selectionsColumn name="ids">
       <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </selectionsColumn>
```

but I don't want to add a checkbox in the grid.

I have read some article where I found that we can give provider in export button but still it's not working.

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">eoureport_hardware_listing.eoureport_hardware_listing_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
```

if anyone knows how we can resolve an issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<columns name="sales_order_columns">
    <selectionsColumn name="ids">
         <settings>
            <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
         </settings>
    </selectionsColumn>
</columns>
```